# Angular 5: Where should type conversion between form field values (strings) and model properties (eg numbers) happen?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and can't figure out, how to convert types between form field values (always strings) and typed model properties.

The following component should double a number. The result is shown in the console.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-view-conversion',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="aNumber" (keyup)="double()" />
  `
})
export class ModelViewConversionComponent {

  aNumber: number;

  double() {
    console.log(this.aNumber + this.aNumber); // input 7 -> 77
  }

}
```

Neither TypeScript nor Angular magically converts between strings and numbers. So the result is of course a concatenation and not the addition. That's only for simple demonstration purpose.

**The question is, where/how should the conversion happen?**

I came up with something like the following:

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-view-conversion',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="viewNumber" (keyup)="double()" />
  `
})
export class ModelViewConversionComponent implements DoCheck {

  viewNumber: string;
  modelNumber: number;

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.modelNumber = parseInt(this.viewNumber);
  }

  double() {
    console.log(this.modelNumber + this.modelNumber); // input 7 -> 14
  }

}
```

This works but does not really help. The model and the view must be kept in sync manually. Their must be something like converters, known from JavaServer Faces for example.

Or what's about getters/setters in the model?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-view-conversion',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="aNumber" (keyup)="double()" />
  `
})
export class ModelViewConversionComponent {

  num: number;
  set aNumber(numAsString) {
    this.num = parseInt(<any>numAsString);
  };
  get aNumber() {
    return this.num;
  }

  double() {
    console.log(this.num + this.num);
  }

}
```

This feels also clumsy and verbose to me. TypeScript (I'm new to TypeScript too) requires the `<any>` cast to compile nicely.

Could anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no conversion. The type depends on the type of the `value` property of the field. `NgModel` deals with any kind of control, so of course, it treats the values as `any`. As the `input` fields is used to display text, its values are always of type `string`. There's no way Angular (and even less TypeScript which only knows about types at compile time) can convert between values. That's entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I'm aware of this. The conversion is up to the developer. But where/how? I'm looking for a good pattern/practice. As examples I showed two possibilities (live cycle hooks and getters/setters). But this solutions just don't feel right. The Angular code examples are impressive and elegant. So for sure I'm missing something or even the whole point.

Comment: Well, I usually make gettters/setters in the component when I need conversion of values or coercion between the view data and the model data. Of course, you can also use controls that use the exact type you need. In this case, `<input type="number">` or a third party control if you've got to deal with browsers that don't support this.

Comment: `<input type="number">` still transfers strings. If browsers support the type, they ensure lets say a "correct number string", but still a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a matter of *when*, but rather a mtter of *how*.

You convert your string to numbers when you need them.

In this particular example, you need them on console logging.

Try that

```
double() {
  if (isNaN(this.modelNumber) { console.log('isNaN(' + this.modelNumber + ')'; return; }
  console.log(+this.modelNumber + +this.modelNumber);
}
```

The conversion to number is very simple, you just append a plus sign before your strings. You simply have to test that they are numbers before doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, converting between Strings and Numbers is trivial. Here it just for demonstrating the pattern. Imagine a more real world model. Assume the Hero class from the angular tutorial. Lets say Heros have an age and other non string properties (dates, custom types). And they have methods like `olderThan(otherHero: Hero)`. So I would like to keep this model objects "clean" and I don't know where the conversion should happen. Setters and getters perhaps are one option.

Comment: As I said, convert them when you need it. You said it yourself, it's trivial, so do it when you need to (comparing, sending a payload ...), it's just one line after all.

Comment: "Just one line after all" but still one line on 10, 100, 500 places? That's not satisfying me at the moment. I have more Java server side background. Perhaps that's the reason. JavaServe Faces address this with converters and validators. The latter are also an Angular concept.

Comment: And you somehow have to call your converters and validators right ? That takes one line on 10, 100, 500 places ? You can make a function to crate complex types of you want, it doesn't change the fact that you will have to call this function. So I stand by my statement, convert it when you need it.

Comment: Hmmm, let me express it in other words. Forget the trivial example. If the model needs numbers, dates, customers or bicycles, only numbers, dates, customers or bicycles should go in the model. You propagate string values for all? For every counting on numbers, dates or whatever one should convert a string to the correct type? That's completely against software/oo design principles. Forms transfer strings. So, somewhere this strings must be converted to model data types. Angular permits many places to do that. Getters/setters/hooks/pipes and probably more. I'm looking for a best/good practice.

Comment: I understood in the first place don't worry. Given your example, you should for instance save this data into the database, or do something with it right ? Well then, on submiting the form, you convert your data to an object. You use it *when* you need it. The user can only input strings or numbers from his keyboard, so you should deal with that, and only convert the data when it's needed.